# $\Delta$-system lemma to show ccc

Tags: set-theory, forcing, transfinite-induction

This is not a hard question but I do not know how to figure it out. Let $X$ and $Y$ be a nonempty sets. 
Let $\langle P,\leq\rangle=\langle P,\supset\rangle$ be be partially ordered where 
$P=\{f:D\to Y\colon D\subset X \ |D|<\omega\}$.   If $|Y|\leq\omega$ then $P$ is ccc, ccc means every antichain at most countable.

Of course, if $P$ is countable, then it follows. Assume $P$ is uncountable,  I think the way that can be done is , let $$ F=\{f_\alpha\colon A_\alpha\to Y\colon A_\alpha\subset X \text{ and } |A_\alpha|<\omega\}$$ and $F\subset P$ and $|F|\geq\omega_1$. It is enough to find two elements in $F$ that are compatible, that is, $f, g\in F$ and $ h\in F$ such that $f\subset h$ and $g\subset h.$ Also, $\Delta$-system lemma will be used to get $P$ ccc.

My attempt, let $f_\alpha, f_\xi\in F$  and show there  are compatible. I think we can assume  all $A_\alpha\neq A_\xi$ for all $\alpha, \xi<\omega_1$ Then by using $\Delta$-system there is a finite set $R$ such that $A_\alpha\cap A_\xi= R$.

If what I said was correct, how I can finish? Otherwise how this can done? Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let G be an uncountable subset of P and let $G\supset F=\{f_a: a\in \omega_1\}\subset P$ where $a\ne a'\implies f_a\ne f_{a'}.$ Let $dom(f_a)=A_a$.

Let $B$ be an uncountable subset of $\omega_1$ such that $D=\{A_a: a\in B\}$ is a $\Delta$-system. Let $A=\cap D.$

There are only countably many $f:A\to Y$ because $A$ is finite and $Y$ is countable. So $\psi(f_a)=f_a|_A$ maps the uncountable set $F^*=\{f_a:a\in B\}$ to the countable set $E=\{f_a|_A:a\in B\}.$

So there exists an uncountable $F^{**}\subset F^*$ and an $e\in E$ such that $\psi(f)=e$ for all $f\in F^{**}.$ Now take just $two$ unequal $f,f'\in F^{**}. $ We have dom($f_a)\cap $dom $(f_{a'})=A$ (because $D$ is a $\Delta$-system), and $f|_A=\psi (f)=e=\psi(f')=f'|_A,$ so $f,f'$ are compatible.

Remark. $f|_A$ means the restriction of a function $f$ to the domain $A$, when $A\subset $ dom($f).$

Comment: In the book Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by K. Kunen, the notation for $P$ is $Fn(X,Y,\omega),$ and in general $\{f: A\to Y\,|\, A\in [X]^{<k}\}=$ $Fn(X,Y,k) $ 
 where $ [X]^{<k}$ is a standard notation for $\{A\subset X: |A|<k\}.$

Comment: $P$ is called the set of finite partial functions from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @DanielWainfeeet, Thank you so much for this beautiful answer .It helps me  a lot

Comment: When I was in a course on Forcing taught by Prof. Franklin Tall, this Q, or one very similar, was assigned. His written note on my work was that it was much easier if you apply the $\Delta$-system lemma to the domains of the functions rather than to the functions,